# Realm issue: Bad changeset received: Assertion failed: left().link_target_table_ndx == right().link_target_table_ndx

Tags: swift, realm

When I open my synced realm, it closes with this message:

```
Bad changeset received: Assertion failed: left().link_target_table_ndx == right().link_target_table_ndx
```

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41121987/how-to-handle-sync-error-bad-changeset-received-assertion-failed-left-link) says that this happens when you're trying to sync two incompatible schemas. However, I've deleted all the local and synced Realms that deal with this data, and then re-created and repopulated the local and synced realms, all using one app, so they have the same schema, don't they? I had previously used a separate app to populate the online realm, and the schema was different and I was getting problems, but I haven't used that app in weeks, and have deleted and re-created the realms since then, so I would imagine this other app shouldn't matter, right?

What's wrong here?

---

Now, I do seem to be able to avert this `Bad changeset` message, and the closing of the realm, by including "/~/" in my realm address, which, if I understand correctly, gets replaced by some device-specific ID. I see this ID tacked on in the realm address when I log onto my server in the realm browser, it makes sense to me. But I would imagine you'd want to leave this out and NOT have a unique ID, otherwise every user is creating their own realm on my server and not even actually syncing with anything at all!

It does occur to me that the address without the `"/~/"` (the problematic one) might be the address I used for the old app I mentioned earlier. But, as I said up there, the realms have been reset so that doesn't make sense. (assuming that deleting realms from the server and then regenerating them from the app is the same thing as resetting!)

This issue is also related to my post [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43506528/strange-behavior-when-connecting-to-synced-realm)

Comment: Bad changeset means the version of client Realm is forwarded than Server Realm. You said you deleted the Realm file. Is it the cause of the issue? Do you reproduce it again on even after setting up a new server?

Comment: Usually accessing a realm that doesn't exist creates that realm. Or do you mean reproduce the error? I don't plan on setting up a new server, that seems unnecessary, no?

Comment: Standalone Realm works so. But you're using synced Realm. It looks like you replaced the Realm synchronized manually, is it correct? If so, it will not work.